# How to diagnose Windows 7 boot problems?

Tags: windows-7, reboot, diagnostic

Is there a way in Windows 7 to see some log file on why the system is trying to boot, then after some time reboots itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's not clear what you've tried already, I'll suggest this to start:

1. [Start Windows 7 in Safe Mode](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/safe-mode-windows-7.htm)
2. Check the logs in the [Windows Event Viewer](http://www.windows7update.com/Windows7-Event-Viewer.html) for [pertinent information](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-information-appears-in-event-logs-Event-Viewer)

Hope that helps get you going.

Comment: This is the info I've found during recovery: `a patch is preventing the system from starting`. Any ideas what to try next? Windows can't recover automatically.

Comment: I think we're hitting a launguage barrier.  What do you mean by 'recovery'?

Comment: This appears to be a known problem with a new update - see http://superuser.com/questions/174950/manually-uninstalling-windows-7-update